# Always visible DatePicker from JavaFX

Tags: java, datepicker, javafx-8

Was wondering is it possible to make a DatePicker that always would be visible? In this case, I would like it to stay visible even after picking the necessary date. Because now, if you click the date, the calendar disappears.

Thank you

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/35650600/203657

Comment: I have posted an answer to the question @kleopatra linked that you might be interested in